# Uniswap Encode Path in typescript

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, encoding

I have a smart contract that is proxying a call to uniswap v3:

```
    function resolveImplementation(uint256 amountIn, SwapResolverOptions memory swapResolverOptions) public returns (uint256 amountOut) {
        
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(swapResolverOptions.inputTokenAddress, _msgSender(), address(this), amountIn);
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(swapResolverOptions.inputTokenAddress, address(router), amountIn);
       
        ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams memory params =
            ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams({
                path: swapResolverOptions.path,
                recipient: swapResolverOptions.destinationAddress,
                //Deadline shouldn't matter since it should execute inline
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: 0
            });

        amountOut = router.exactInput(params);
    }
```

I keep getting errors when trying to perform the multihop swap

```js
>cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xdC226AC64e36fA4214E827071e8467B3bD3a5f28","to":"0x45f052eD6EDDBCa3B1868dCE83Db79F41D4bEd61",,"accessList":null}, error={"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.6.8)
```

I've created to different functions to try to encode the path neither seem to work.

```js
      function encodePathPacked(pathValues: { address: string; fee: number }[], outputAddress: string): string {
        
        const hexValues: any[] = [];
        for (const pathValue of pathValues) {
          const rawHexAddress = pathValue.address.slice(2);
          console.log(`address: ${rawHexAddress}`)
          let rawFee = web3.utils.toHex(pathValue.fee).toString()
          console.log(`raw fee hex: ${rawFee}`)
          
          hexValues.push(rawHexAddress);
          hexValues.push(rawFee.slice(2).padStart(6,"0"));
        }
        hexValues.push(outputAddress.slice(2))

        let path = '0x'+hexValues.join("");
        return defaultAbiCoder.encode(["bytes"], [path]);
      }

      function encodePath(pathValues: { address: string; fee: number }[], outputAddress: string): string {
        const pairSignature = 'address, uint24,';
        const pathAbiStart = '(';
        const pathAbiEnd = 'address)';
      
        const values: any[] = [];
        let pathAbi = pathAbiStart;
        for (const pathValue of pathValues) {
          pathAbi += pairSignature;
          values.push(pathValue.address);
          values.push(pathValue.fee);
        }
        values.push(outputAddress)
        pathAbi += pathAbiEnd;
      
        
        return defaultAbiCoder.encode([pathAbi], [values]);
      }
```

I've verified the router works using a single hop, so its not the router, and nor the amount in, the other parameters should be fine. It appears to be the path.

How can I encode a path to perform a multihop swap?

**Note:** I've also tried without the final `encode(["bytes"], [path])` the encoding was translated uniswaps tests [here](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/6cce88e63e176af1ddb6cc56e029110289622317/test/shared/path.ts#L9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have a tuple on `exactInput()` as we do in `exactInputSingle()`.

This is the function that i use to encode the path:

```
function encodePath(path, fees) {
    if (path.length != fees.length + 1) {
      throw new Error('path/fee lengths do not match')
    }
    
  
    let encoded = '0x'
    for (let i = 0; i < fees.length; i++) {
      // 20 byte encoding of the address
      encoded += String(path[i]).slice(2)
      // 3 byte encoding of the fee
      encoded += fees[i]
    }
    // encode the final token
    encoded += path[path.length - 1].slice(2)
  
    return encoded.toLowerCase()
  }
```

It's adapted from the one that the tests from the sdk use to verify if they class works well.

Check this random encoded that i picked from etherscan:

`0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc20001f4a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48000bb8dac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7`

First part is the token of the input:

`0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2`

Second part is the fee from the pool input/between, it has 6 digitis, the three last is the fee hexflied without `0x` in front of it. The three first digits are always `000`:

`0001f4`

The third part is the address of the between token without the `0x`:

`a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48`

The fourth part is the fee for the pool from the between token and the output token:

`000bb8`

Last portion is the address of the output without `0x`:

`bb8dac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7`

Went as didact as i could.

Comment: The SDK V3 has an method for encoding also!

Comment: Whats the method in the sdk

Comment: `encodeRouteToPath`

Comment: If awnser your quest please mark que my awnser.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rodrigo answer and seeking in uniswap official code, here is the correct typescript code:

```typescript
const encodePath = (path: string[], fees: number[]): string => {
    if (path.length != fees.length + 1) {
      throw new Error("path/fee lengths do not match");
    }

    let encoded = "0x";
    for (let i = 0; i < fees.length; i++) {
      // 20 byte encoding of the address
      encoded += path[i].slice(2);
      // 3 byte encoding of the fee
      encoded += fees[i].toString(16).padStart(2 * 3, "0");
    }
    // encode the final token
    encoded += path[path.length - 1].slice(2);

    return encoded.toLowerCase();
}

// example
encodePath(["0x000", "0x000", "0x000"], [500,500]);
```